# How to assign variable and increment/decrement its value dynamically in limit filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="*">
<div ng-repeat="item in list | limitTo:limit">
   ...content
</div>
<div ng-if="list.item.size > 10">
<button ng-click="incrementForEachItem(limit, false)">load less</button>
<button ng-click="decrementForEachItem(limit, true)">load more</button>
</div>
</div>
```

I have some lists displaying in each repetition on different sections with a base limit of 10, buttons are conditionally appearing in sections having items more than the condition.

Controller code is:

```
$scope.limit = 10;
$scope.incrementForEachItem = function(limit, status) {
    if(resource === 'platforms') {
        (status) ? $scope.limit += 10 : $scope.limit = 10;
    }
    console.log(this.resource);
};
```

Everything is working except the variable that I sat on the scope is getting incremented for each. how can I assign variable to limitTo on each repetition of item. Items are different.

**Edit 1:** More detail

there are two nested `ng-repeat` on the view. For each of that element I need to only show 10 elements. To handle more elements I have to add buttons through which I can handle the data. I also have handled the data but the issue is I have one variable in the `$scope` which limits the data from displaying. The issue is The buttons are interacting with the same **scope variable**, so lets say if you hit show more on some element it shows +10 data for that plus it got applied to the other component as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this. Here is what I did in steps:

**Step 1:** Where `ng-repeat` was declared, I assigned the index to a variable to track the loop.

```
$parentIndex = $index;
```

**Step 2:** Inside the controller I created an array equals to the length of the list which was getting iterated on the view.

```
var limitConstants = [10, 10, 10] // the number of elements you want to display.
```

**Step 3:** On click of show less/more button I passed the `$parentIndex`.
**Step 4:** Then inside the event listeners I was able to modify the size of the elements of each levels using the `$parentIndex` as the index for the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    HTML + Controller:
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ng-init="limitInit=10">
            <span ng-repeat="dat in res | limitTo: limitInit track by $index" >
            {{dat}} {{dat.length}}
            <span ng-repeat="da in dat.sub | limitTo: limitInit track by $index">
              {{da}}
            </span>
            <span>....</span>
        </span>
        <button  ng-click="limitInit=limitInit+10;">load more</button>
        <button ng-click="limitInit=10">load less</button>
        </div>
        <script>
          var app= angular.module("myApp", []);

          app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http){
              $http.get('data.json').then(function(data){
                  $scope.res= data.data;
                  console.log("The res " +JSON.stringify($scope.res));
              });
          } );

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
  JSON
  [
    {
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    },{
        "name":"testOne",
        "sub":["a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h","a","b","c","d","e", "f", "g", "h"]
    }
    ]
```

Comment: as I can see you're declaring the variable inside ng-init, which means it does initialize as soon as the view is loaded, but it's the same variable for each repeat. I doubt that would work. Do you have plunkr or something? thanks for your effort buddy.

Comment: No i did according to json.. i perceived.. yes that show more and less is common to both fields..